# I don't understand what is within the brackets of some sample code

Tags: python

I have a simple two lines of code but fail to understand what is actually happening.

```
    s = 'We\'re' + 'Here'
    print(s[4::2])
```

The result is just *eee*. I fail to see how the [4::2] is working to cause the code to print *eee*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something like `[start: end: step]`, slice addresses can be written as s[start:end:step] and **any of start, stop or end can be dropped**. So, s[4::2] is starting from 4th and every 2nd element of the sequence(Here you dropped the end part). That's why it is returning `eee`

```
s = 'We\'re' + 'Here'
print(s[4::2])
```